# Reference for boundedness and constructibility of $Ri^! \mathcal{E}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/324215/138661) David Hansen says

> By hard results of Deligne, Grothendieck, and Gabber, $Ri^! \mathcal{E}$ is still bounded and constructible...

What are these results of Deligne, Grothendieck and Gabber? What is the reference where I can find them?

Comment: I think David's referring to the existence of a six operations formalism of étale sheaves that preserves constructibility and has expected properties (something that's hard to summarize in a single theorem). So the sentence "by hard results of Deligne, Grothendieck, and Gabber" should be read as "according to something which is probably in SGA4".

Comment: @DanPetersen but when either SGA 4 or SGA 4.5 was published, Ofer Gabber was <20 years old. Does Gabber have any relationship whatsoever to either of those two texts?

Comment: That's a good point. What I should have said is that in SGA4-4½-5 this is proven when the base scheme is of dimension $\leq 1$ and some other technical assumptions, and that these hypotheses were later removed by Gabber. A reference is "Travaux de Gabber".